# How to clear all osm tiles cache on my own server

Tags: caching, openstreetmap, mapnik

I'm currently working on a map project, based on OpenStreetMap, using Mapnik, renderd and mod_tile (like osm do on their website).
I've built an osm tiles server, following some tutorials, on my personal computer (Ubuntu 12.04).
It works well, and i've loaded a lot of regions of one country (not the entire planet, just some piece of the planet).

I realized that mod_tile was using a cache for each tiles rendered, so i decided to investigate **how i can clear that**.
[The only solution i found so far](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_expire_methods) was to use the `render_expired` binary, but i don't understand how i can set all tiles to expired by this way (moreover without diff files)...
I was trying to find where these images are located but i don't find them.

I need some help, so if someone has an idea ...

Comment: After hours of investigations, i finally found these images here: `/var/lib/mod_tile/default`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just remove the mentioned `/var/lib/mod_tile/default` (using `rm -rf` if you dare) and restart renderd daemon.

Comment: How to restart renderd daemon properly without `killall renderd`? Also now I get a 404 instead of a newly rendered png images.

Answer (score 4):

Run this:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mod_tile/ajt
sudo service renderd restart
```

ajt is your tile folder which may be different and there may be more than one.

If you accidentally removed your ajt (or any other) folder itself:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mod_tile/ajt
sudo chown renderaccount /var/lib/mod_tile/ajt
```

Answer (score 2):

This helped me without restart `find /var/cache/renderd/tiles/ -type f -delete` .

Comment: This is what worked for me in 2023.